# Software installation wine

Tags: software-installation, wine

[image]

Been trying to install league for a while now but this comes up with a new error appearing every time i say okay

Answer (score 1):

I installed LoL myself under WINE and it ran just fine on 15.10. However, I utilized a program called [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/) to help with the installation.

PlayOnLinux is really useful because it hides a bunch of the complexity of WINE and gives a nice GUI, it keeps all of the programs installed through it in separate virtual drives, so if one program messes something up it doesn't take all of the rest of your WINE programs with it, and has the ability to download & install tons of programs and games directly from the GUI.

As for installing LoL with PlayOnLinux, there are just a few steps. You'll need to use the terminal for this bit, you can open it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>.

First, you'll need to add the NoobsLab PPA. This will let you get a newer version of PlayOnLinux (with bug fixes and improvements) than the one in the default Ubuntu repositories. This can be done by running these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, you'll need to install the i386 version of WINE and PlayOnLinux:

```
sudo apt-get install wine:i386 playonlinux
```

Once that completes, you can go ahead and launch PlayOnLinux via either the Unity Menu or via running `playonlinux` in Terminal.

You may have to go through a setup that involves downloading a few more files that PlayOnLinux needs, depending on how you have your system set up. Just complete that and continue on.

Once you have PlayOnLinux up and running, you're going to want to click the **Install** button:

[image]

This will bring up a new window in which you can search for programs and games. From there you're going to want to search `League` in the search box and it will bring up League of Legends as the only option:

[image]

If you select the **Install** button a wizard will show up and guide you through the installation:

[image]

Just follow those steps and you should soon have a working LoL installation!

Comment: Upgrade. You said you have 15.10

Comment: @ubashu Oh, I have long since upgraded to 16.04. It's just that when I *first* installed LoL, it was on 15.10

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what version of Ubuntu, Wine, and LoL. However, if you check the Wine app database, you may find your answer.

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10436

For LoL v6:

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33303

Do a little digging on these pages. Cheers, Al